# Is it ok to bring a pen onto an international airplane (US to Pol)?

Tags: air-travel, regulations, hand-luggage

I'm traveling to Poland in a few days, and i wonder if pens are allowed on an airplane. I know you cannot bring sharp objects like small scissors and i see no reason why pens should be an exception.

Comment: The fact this question is appropriate makes me sad.

Comment: True story: a coworker was trying, shortly after 9/11, to keep the exacto knives he had left in his carryon, because he needed them to set up conference equipment on arrival. He said "but you could kill someone with a pen!". Another coworker in line behind is praying "shut up! shut up!" - he was carrying 200 pens for giveaways. BTW the pens were allowed and the knives were not.

Comment: I would think they would say it's too much like a club.

Comment: I wonder how an old-fashioned sharpened feather quill would do.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I guess while pens in theory could be used to cause pain, as could some types of shoes or household keys, and they're allowed.  I assure you, you'll have zero problem taking an ordinary ballpoint or ink pen (or pencil) on a flight - unless you have some weird pen in the shape of a dagger or something :)

Comment: thank you. Yea airport security always seemed like a joke to me. They try to make people feel safe but really in the right hands there are a lot of objects which are really dangerous. (and personally i feel like pen is more dangerous then the tiny scissors they disallow)

Comment: @Xitcod13 It's called security theatre.